# How do I fix HTTP Status 404 - Not Found on Intellij IDEA?

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I've started my first job 2 months ago and it's been awhile since I've dealt with Spring. I'm trying to run Tomcat server, and display "/home" but I'm getting 404 on it. When I hover at my "home", IntelliJ IDEA is showing `home.html` . Error

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/home] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.65
```

HTTP error
[image]

Code folders screenshot

[image]

Tomcat config
[image]

Tomcat deployment config

[image]

I've googled about it but it's doesn't fix it. Here is my code.

File `HomeController.java`

```java
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
public String landingPage() {
        return ("home");
    }
}
```

File `home.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Landing page</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

File `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I also tried to run my older projects that works but now it doesn't.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please post the code and error as text, not an image.

Comment: code is a text not image. I'll edit the error.

Comment: What URL is used to open home page?

Comment: This is the url http://localhost:8080/home

Answer (score 0):

try to use `ModelAndView`:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index () {
   ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
   modelAndView.setViewName("home");
   return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: Not needed, the controller is correct as is. (Although I would personally use `GetMapping` instead of `RequestMapping` for clarity).

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Boot, which has an embedded Tomcat server. I believe you have a standalone Tomcat running on port 8080 on your machine, preventing Spring Boot from using its own embedded Tomcat.

Stop the standalone Tomcat and start the Spring Boot application again.

Comment: Good morning! I did but now I'm getting Port 8080 was already in use. Tried to kill the process using commands I found on stack but nothing seems to be killing it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good. Spring boot doesn't require you to do any tomcat configuration.

The configuration you have should be the problem. Re create the project without the Tom Cat config and deployment config.

Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYGnVeCs0Yg&t=4235s

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers mentioned before, you're using Spring Boot, which has its embedded Tomcat server under the hood. It's the default behavior, but you may configure your Spring Boot project to use Netty or Undertow servers, please check more details here — [Embedded Web Servers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html)

So since you already have the Tomcat server, there is no need to configure it in your IDE. Also, worth mentioning that running a project from your IDE is not the best idea. Especially, when you're describing your steps for reproducing the issue to someone else. Instead, you may run your Spring Boot project from the command line using the such command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

By default, it'll start your application on the 8080 port and you will be able to access your homepage at this URL: `localhost:8080/home`

For more details on running your Spring Boot application, you may check this document — [Running your application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html)

To run the Spring Boot project from your IntelliJ IDEA, you need to open the DemoApplication class (in your case), which has the main method. And on the left, there should be a play button for running your project. You can also configure it in the 'Edit configurations' menu by selecting the 'Spring Boot' item under the 'Add new configuration' menu.

**Updated:**

I'm using that you're using macOS. To identify the process running on the 8080 port, which prevents you from starting your Spring Boot application, you may use such command:

```bash
sudo lsof -i :8080
```

This is the example output of this command from my machine, which has the Docker container running on the 8080 port:

```bash
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 3134 golovnya  174u  IPv6 0xcaf3b5f3fb45111      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

Here we're interested in PID, which stands for the process identifier. It's a unique id of the running application. In my case, the PID of the process running on the 8080 port is 3134. Knowing this, we may kill this process by the following command:

```bash
kill -9 <PID>
```

In my case it will look like this:

```bash
kill -9 3134
```

That's all.

P.S. If it looks a bit complicated to your or you experience some issues, reloading your machine is always not a bad idea.

Comment: Hi Alexander. I'm trying to run it now using what you suggested but Port 8080 was already in use.

Comment: I've trying all the commands I see on stackoverflow to kill the 8080 process. Nothing seems to be working on killing the process.

Comment: @jonas Which operating system do you have?

Comment: @jonas Please see the updated section in my answer. I've added commands for shutting downing the process on macOS. If it won't work for you, try to reload your computer (it helps almost any time).